# before and after login view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

since I'm super new to Flutter, what is it called when you have some access to the application before login, but after login you have access to whole app.

if you don't get what I'm saying, I try to explain in some examples.

When I download an app from AppStore, Google Play.
I can take a look at some part like main UI and other stuff in main page.
but for section, pages and etc..., I need to login to see them.
it shows some property before login and others after login.

what is it called and what is the best recommendation to work with in Flutter?

**Many thanks for your time**

Comment: I think you are referring to `Guest Mode`.

Comment: Yes, guest mode is it called that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean authorization, check this for example [Get Started with Flutter Authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-flutter-authentication/)